# Why is my relay switching on automatically when I start my program?

Tags: rpi.gpio, i2c, python-3, relay, adafruit

I'm building a little automated hydroponics system using a raspberry pi zero, a 5 volt relay, a pump and a soil moisture sensor from adafruit. So far everything is working, I can pull the pin to high and engaged the pump via the relay, I can get data from the soil-sensor.

I wrote a test to see if I could make it only print the readout from the sensor if the value of the read was over a certain amount and then activate it with my finger. This works great, it starts and stops if the value is greater than 600 or less than 600... However if I add the line to pull the pin to high in place of the Print function, it simply pulls the pin to high until I kill the program. What am I missing here?

My Test program:

```
import time

import board

from board import SCL, SDA

import busio

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

RELAIS_1_GPIO = 18

GPIO.setup(RELAIS_1_GPIO, GPIO.OUT) # GPIO Assign mode


from adafruit_seesaw.seesaw import Seesaw

i2c_bus = busio.I2C(SCL, SDA)

ss = Seesaw(i2c_bus, addr=0x36)

while True:
    # read moisture level through capacitive touch pad
    touch = ss.moisture_read()

    if touch > 600:
        GPIO.output(RELAIS_1_GPIO, GPIO.HIGH)
        print("moisture: " + str(touch))
```

Comment: Ah, let me see. You described you problem well and detailed, and test procedure is good. But there is one thing at the end not very clear. Did you mean that your programs HANGS after setting a GPIO pin High?

Comment: Try using paragraphs - this monolithic block is difficult to read. Also if you are using foreign libraries include links.

Comment: This is a simple programming question and off-topic. You set the pin High but never reset it so it stays High.

Comment: Please confirm you are using the following hardware and software: (1) Adafruit ATSAMD09 Breakout with seesaw
https://www.adafruit.com/product/3657
(2) SeeSaw Library: https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/seesaw/en/1.5.6/_modules/adafruit_seesaw/seesaw.html

Comment: And are you using this SeeSaw reference/tutorial? https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-seesaw-atsamd09-breakout?view=all

Comment: Very confusing. Are you really using RpiZero and NOT ATSAMD09 and CircuitPython SeeSaw stuff ?

Comment: why do you believe that the output pin will reset to low on its own?

Comment: the sensor uses the adafruit libraries, I followed their tutorial to set it up with the raspberry pi zero. The sensor functions perfectly, the relay turns on if I set the pin to high. The relay turns on if I set the pin to low. it does this with or without the rest of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your help in diagnosing this. Relay was faulty, swapped for one of the same make and model and now its working with the test provided by Coder Mike, as well as my original script.

Answer (score 1):

OBSERVATION: I do not see a line of code / instruction to pull the GPIO back to low.  If the observation is correct and this instruction is executed:

```
GPIO.output(RELAIS_1_GPIO, GPIO.HIGH)
```

- How would the line GPIO return to a low state?
- Under what condition do you expect the GPIO to return to the low state?

What happens if the instructions is changed to:

```
GPIO.output(RELAIS_1_GPIO, GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: Both GPIO.output(RELAIS_1_GPIO, GPIO.LOW) and GPIO.output(RELAIS_1_GPIO, GPIO.HIGH) trigger the relay. If I comment out that line it does not. The rest of my test runs perfectly with or without it.  Am I importing the wrong library for the gpio?

Comment: What do you mean by LOW and HIGH trigger the relay? Normally with a relay LOW is relay ON, HIGH is relay OFF. Is your relay compatible with the 3.3V GPIO pins on the Pi - post a link to the relay your using.

Comment: @NareikSelvad   Your question can not be answered with out knowing which relay board you are using.  I suggest that you follow the instructions provided by the relay board and test GPIO.output() commands as prescribed and post results to determine if they meet expectations.

Comment: An answer should not contain questions to be answered to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a GPIO pin has a latching behavior. That is when you set it, it stays that same value until you tell it otherwise.  So in your if statement, just add an else clause to reset it low if the value read is <=600:

```
if touch > 600:
    GPIO.output(RELAIS_1_GPIO, GPIO.HIGH)
    print("moisture: " + str(touch))
else:
    GPIO.output(RELAIS_1_GPIO, GPIO.LOW)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the following turn on and off your relay accordingly?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
RELAIS_1_GPIO = 18
GPIO.setup(RELAIS_1_GPIO, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    print('on')
    GPIO.output(RELAIS_1_GPIO, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(2)

    print('off')
    GPIO.output(RELAIS_1_GPIO, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: No :/ the relay is still active even when printing off